# Printing Pictureboxes onto a map using 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays

The map is a picturebox which has been mapped onto a 2d array which looks like this:  (this is going to be a top-down rpg)

```
public void Create_Map()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) // runs down the rows and columns of the array
    {
             for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++)
             {
                 switch (Map[i, x])
                 {
                     case 0:


                         break;
                     case 1:

                         // the purpose of this is to create invisible walls
                         // ontop of the map to stop the player if they 
                         // collide
                         Bitmap image2 = new Bitmap("FAL1.bmp"); 
                         fal[i,x] = new PictureBox();
                         this.Controls.Add(fal[i,x]);
                         fal[i,x].Size = new Size(16, 16);
                         fal[i,x].Tag = "Fal";
                         fal[i,x].Image = image2;
                         fal[i,x].Location = new Point(i * 16, x * 16);

                         DoubleBuffered = true;
                         fal[i,x].Parent = mp; //mp is the map picturebox which moves along with the player and to make sure these smaller picture boxes follow it too i set it as parent

                         break;
                     case 2:

                         break;
                     case 3:



                         // creates the player   
                          Bitmap image3 = new Bitmap("HERO.PNG"); 
                         hero = new PictureBox();
                         this.Controls.Add(hero);
                         hero.Size = new Size(20, 18);
                         hero.Tag = "Fal";
                         hero.Image = image3;
                         hero.Location = new Point(i * 16, x * 16);
                         this.BringToFront();
                         DoubleBuffered = true;
                         hero.Parent = mp;
                         hero.BackColor = Color.Transparent;


                         break;


                 }
             }
    }
}
```

This is the array:

```
 public int[,] Map = new int[60,60]


            {
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
               {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},



            };
```

I want the character to basically bounce back if it collides with the wall. This is the code:

```
private void Up_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // this is the timer which move the character up 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++)
            {
                if (hero.Bounds.IntersectsWith(fal[i,x].Bounds))  
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("collide");

                }
            }
        }
            hero.Location = new Point(hero.Location.X, hero.Location.Y - 2);
            mp.Location = new Point(mp.Location.X, mp.Location.Y + 2); 
            // mp is the picturebox which is used as the map. the window is smaller than the map so this is how i tried to make it seem like the window is following the player
    }
```

this is where the issue is. if i create the fal picturebox as a 2d array it will give a null error. if i try to do it as a single dimensional array each row will be over written by the next row and only one row will actually exist but all the other picture boxes will also be printed its just that the computer doesnt recognise them.

this is the way I declared the picturebox array:

```
 PictureBox[,] fal = new PictureBox[60,60];
```

So the question is, how can I print all of these pictureboxes out or put them in an array without getting error, or what am I doing wrong? I'm new to programming and I did everything by myself so it is possible that my entire idea is wrong?

Also I'm not using any engine and I don't want to

Comment: oh thats because i made modifications and forgot to change them back, still it doesnt work even if i acces it as an array. its supposed to be fal[x,i]

Comment: It seems wasteful to check all 3600 cells each time you want to check for a collision.  It seems like you would only need to check the one above, below, left or right.  Also, having 3600 `PicutreBox`ex on the form seems like it would not be very performant and have lots of flicker.  I would think having a single large `PictureBox` for the map and then drawing the different bitmaps in their proper locations would be better.  The bitmaps could be loaded ahead of time and always be available.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean as my map is indeed one big picture. the create map array is only used for generating 16x16 big squares of pictureboxes as invisible walls ontop of my map to act as a barrier. as im new to programming i dont understand what you mean by "drawing bitmaps in their proper locations" but  that is kind of what i was trying to accomplish. if there is another way i would really appreciate an explanation. sorry for the bother